How to invoke a js function after every page is created?
In my Vue2 app, it's easy enough to call a JavaScript function in the created() method of every .vue file. Not wanting to do this in every file, am I able to invoke a JS function on creation (or mount) of every page? If so, how?
$router.beforeEach and afterEach are out of the question as they are obviously not called when a component is created/mounted.

may I know why you want to do it inside created()?

If you do not want to repeat your code many times I would recommend using mixins.

@Damzaky It is because we want to track time spent on a page by a user for an in-house tracking/analytic engine.

@TymoteuszLao Thanks for the recommendation. I read through the link and it says  Mixin hooks will be called before the component’s own hooks. - that defeats my purpose because I want the method to be called only on either created/mounted lifecycle hooks.

I have not tested this, but maybe you can try this

you can use global mixins and invoke function on create or mounted

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
